# Docker anaconda manifest not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to run docker file but it says this on step 1/6

'''
manifest for continuumio/anaconda3:4.9.2 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
'''

[This is the error it is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWDlE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting such message because that tag is not available in Docker Hub. Choosing another image version may solve your problem :)

You can check the available `continuumio/anaconda3` tags here https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It worked after removing the anaconda version from the dockerfile.

Comment: Glad to help. Please note that [continuumio/anaconda](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda) is based on Python 2.7, whereas [continuumio/anaconda3](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3) is based on Python 3.5